# Source Unreachable issue in installing Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: entity-framework

I am having issues with installing Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2013. I am having following error.

> The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local >Cache at C:\Users\9040\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
>   Install-Package : Unable to read package from path 'EntityFramework.6.1.2.nupkg'.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + install-package <<<<  EntityFramework
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidDataException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : >NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got it solved. Thought i should share it. I don't know why but Package console does not pick source path from Package Manager Settings. I explicitly had to state the path with Install command and it worked. This is the command

> Install-Package EntityFramework -Source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

Thanks